# Get definite values from string

Tags: python

I need to get the values of 'name' from such string

```
[{'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/11207132',
  'id': '11207',    
  'name': 'SEO'},    
 {'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/12200123',    
  'id': '12200',    
  'name': 'НКК'}]
```

I want to get an output like `'SEO','HKK'` all in one string.

Comment: How do we access elements of an array? You use indexing, i.e. `e = arr[0]` which would return the first element, `e`. What's `e`? It's a dictionary, and how do we access values of a dictionary? Via a key, i.e. `name = e['name']`, which returns `'SEO'`! Can you extrapolate that to an iterative solution?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
data = [{'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/11207132',
  'id': '11207',    
  'name': 'SEO'},    
 {'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/12200123',    
  'id': '12200',    
  'name': 'НКК'}]

print(','.join([f"'{x['name']}'" for x in data]))
```

**Output:**

```
"'SEO','НКК'"
```

**Explanation:**
The list comprehension creates a flat list comprised of values corresponding to the `name` key for every dictionary in `data`. Then we simply wrap those elements in quotes and `join` them in a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dictionaries. All you need to do is to iterate over the dictionaries and to keep the `name` key of each one of them:

```
entities = [{'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/11207132', 'id': '11207', 'name': 'SEO'},
            {'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/12200123', 'id': '12200', 'name': 'НКК'}]

result = []
for entity in entities:
    result.append(entity['name'])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['SEO', 'НКК']
```

Comment: Thanks you all, friends! You realy helped me!

Answer (score 0):

If your input is not an array or dictionary, but a string you can not directly access the data. You can use `json`:

```
import json
def get_names(components: str):
    # prevent error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
    components = components.replace('\'', '"')
    # convert string to json
    components = json.loads(components)
    # create empty list
    names = []
    # iterate through components
    for component in components:
        # append name to list
        names.append(component['name'])
    # return list
    return names

s = """[{'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/11207132',
  'id': '11207',    
  'name': 'SEO'},    
 {'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/12200123',    
  'id': '12200',    
  'name': 'НКК'}]"""
print(get_names(s))
```

Output:

```
['SEO', 'НКК']
```

To get your requested Output you can do:

```
print(', '.join(["'"+i+"'" for i in get_names(s)]))
```

This will give you:

```
'SEO', 'НКК'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want your name data stored, but something like this will work:

```
dicts = [
{'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/11207132',
 'id': '11207',
 'name': 'SEO'},
{'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/12200123',
 'id': '12200',
 'name': 'НКК'}
]

names_only = [i['name'] for i in dicts]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should extract and format the names as you indicate:

```
dx = [{'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/11207132',
       'id': '11207',    
       'name': 'SEO'},    
      {'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/component/12200123',    
       'id': '12200',    
       'name': 'НКК'}] 

names = ", ".join(["'{}'".format(item.get('name')) for item in dx])
print(names)
```

Putting this into the REPL shows:

```
>>> print(names)
'SEO', 'НКК'
```